# Flexbox 'flex-wrap' on the element not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

So I want the divs in the 'header-content-lower' element to wrap down (if they all do not fit on the screen) in a row but its not even working, I tried changing box-sizing of the childs or setting max-width of the parent element but I still do not have a clue whats wrong, please help, im so done -  this is my code:

```css
@import "main.css";
.site-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
}

.header-content-upper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  color: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.header-content-upper .header-brand {
  color: var(--main-font);
  font-family: Glosa;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.header-content-upper .header-nav {
  text-align: end;
}

.header-content-upper li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-content-lower {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--second-font);
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.header-content-lower div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  color: var(--second-font);
}

.header-content-lower div:nth-child(2n-1) {
  border: 1px solid var(--second-font);
  border-width: 0px 1px 0 1px;
}

.header-brand,
.header-news,
.header-nav {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="header-content-upper">
    <nav class="header-news">Subscribe & get 15% OFF</nav>
    <span class="header-brand">Giovanni</span>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Call + (448) 777 55 00</li>
        <li>CART (0)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content-lower">
    <div>HOME</div>
    <div>MENU</div>
    <div>ORDER</div>
    <div>BLOG</div>
    <div>CONTACT</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It's working, for example, if I set the container width to `10px` it does wrap. Problem is your divs and spacing between them adapt to your container size, so make them fixed and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It won't wrap since you defined a fixed width for `.header-content-lower`. This will make the container stay 1000px wide, even if the screen is smaller.

Replace `width: 1000px;` with `max-width: 1000px;`, remove `flex: 1;` from the child divs of `.header-content-lower`, and set a fixed width for them (e.g. width: 200px; so that they have the same width as in your example).

You need to play around with `align-items` and `justify-content` on `.header-content-lower` to change the behavior when wrapped, e.g. with a media query which targets a window width < 1000px.

```css
@import "main.css";
.site-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  height: 150px;
}

.header-content-upper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  color: var(--main-font);
  font-size: 1.1vw;
}

.header-content-upper .header-brand {
  color: var(--main-font);
  font-family: Glosa;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.header-content-upper .header-nav {
  text-align: end;
}

.header-content-upper li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header-content-lower {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--second-font);
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.header-content-lower div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* flex: 1;*/
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  color: var(--second-font);
}

.header-content-lower div:nth-child(2n-1) {
  border: 1px solid var(--second-font);
  border-width: 0px 1px 0 1px;
}

.header-brand,
.header-news,
.header-nav {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="header-content-upper">
    <nav class="header-news">Subscribe & get 15% OFF</nav>
    <span class="header-brand">Giovanni</span>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Call + (448) 777 55 00</li>
        <li>CART (0)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content-lower">
    <div>HOME</div>
    <div>MENU</div>
    <div>ORDER</div>
    <div>BLOG</div>
    <div>CONTACT</div>
  </div>
</header>
```